# Why can't I prove this set of vectors spans

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm asked if the matrices

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\
3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
-3 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 4\\
5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

span $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$.

I know that the traces of each of them are $0$ so they can't possibly span $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ since you can't write them as a linear combination with matrices that have non-zero traces.

However, I also attempted to do this with a system of equations. If I make a coefficient matrix from this, I get:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
1 & 3 & -3 & 5 \\
-1 & 0 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

After row reducing, I get:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -13/7 \\
0& 1 & 0& 19/7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3/7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

this means the last variable is free and I have a consistent solution and hence, should span $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ but it doesn't.

Why is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Your proof shows that the matrices do **not** span $M_2$.

Comment: Your reduced matrix has rank three (since it has only three nonzero rows) which shows it spans a three dimensional space, hence not the whole four-dimensional space of matrices.

Comment: I get that and honestly that makes perfect sense! However, if I look at the last column, isn't that a free variable? Would that not imply that I have a consistent solution since the last coordinate vector can be anything I want?

Comment: That's exactly what a free variable means. But it's a free variable in the subspace, not all of the space because it's four vectors living in a $3$ dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the last row is equal to zero, you won't be able to generate a vector having the last coordinate not equal to zero.

Hence those four matrices can't span $M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Ohh yes. Of course! That was silly. So because the last coordinate is always 0, I can't possibly be able to get the last coordinate in any way in the case of linear combinations so I can't describe all of $M_2\mathbb{R}$ since one of the coordinate vectors can't be expressed in terms of others as it is always $0$.

Thanks! That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Actually wait. Doesn't the last column imply that the last coordinate vector is free so it can be anything? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: No, the last coordinate will always be $0x+0y+0z+0t = 0$.

Comment: Ahh yes. So essentially, the span of the set of vectors means that I have to let my linear combinations equal an arbritary matrix in this space. However, I get that the last coordinate is 0 so I can't describe this space with just 3 coordinate vectors. Is that the right idea?

Comment: Yes it is the right idea !